# (Mixing 1st/3rd Person in same sentence) Is anyone knowledgeable in this grammar?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-person

TLDR: The prompt below contains autobiographical examples that I believe to be incorporating both first and third person in the same sentences; I am unsure of how to proceed.

I am to adhere to the following format for an autobiographical exposé:

> Guillermo
>
> Short, Tanned skin, and funny
>
> Lover of video games, beanies, and family
>
> Who feels as if life is a tough puzzle to crack
>
> Who needs to support family before self because those are my priorities
>
> Who gives my love to my family and education
>
> Who fears becoming jobless or homeless
>
> Who would like to see my family and myself own a house someday
>
> Who majors in Construction Technology
>
> Who would like to graduate with an Associates Degree
>
> Castaneda

Thus far I've written:

> Blake
>
> Pensive, Impartial, and Curious
>
> Admirer of expression, mindfulness, and delight
>
> Who feels as if life's meaning is but to loiter
>
> Who needs to find ample means concurrent with his favor

My question, is shall I amend "his favor" to "my favor" and continue as such until I am through as was written in the prompt? Or should I write this piece about myself in the third person?

Thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: This should all be in 3rd person.

Comment: Who will read this when you're done? If it's for your own use, then it doesn't matter what person or tense or language you use.

Comment: This is an assignment that will be read by fellow classmates as well as my instructor (and is not an ENG class but a GUID class). A great many thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend **NOT** going by the example given and simply using 3rd person for every phrase that begins with "who". Whenever you hear someone describe themselves to someone else, they will use 1st person until they start referring to themselves by a non-1st-person pronoun, such as "who", after which they use the 3rd person until the end of the phrase.

Example:

> ***I*** am a man ***who*** worries a lot for ***his*** family.
>
> ***I***, ***who*** ***majors*** in Construction Technology and loves ***his*** family, ***need*** to support family before self because those are ***my*** priorities.

However, it would also depend on the circumstance of the prompt. Is the example above yours the given example from the instructor of your class, or is it an example given from an outside source? If the instructor of your class gave you that example, then I'd say do your best to mix the pronouns in the same places the teacher does, and later question them about it, because that just sounds ***weird***, at least to me.

Comment: I suspected as such that once third person was used in the manner that it was that the course of action would be to carry on using it. I appreciated reading your examples of cases in which 3rd and 1st person blend appropriately, and must agree that the prompt sounds off.

This was issued by the instructor, though I noted it appears to be a student sample as my instructor's name and that found in the example are different. I noted that thus far four student's have carried on in the same somewhat awkward manner; I will silently break the mold.

I extend my utmost gratitude to you!

Comment: 'I, who majors in Construction Technology and loves his family' is gruesome.